# JPA - optional = true still giving PropertyValueException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Using Hibernate 5 as ORM.

I use to think that `optional=true` meant that the column could hold null values.

I have two entities -:

- Elective
- ElectivePractical

An Elective may or may not be associated with an ElectivePractical but an ElectivePractical must always be associated with an Elective.

Elective.java

```
public class Elective extends Theory {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column (name = "ELEC_NO", 
            table = "ELECTIVES", 
            length = 3)
    private String electiveNo;

    @OneToOne (targetEntity = ElectivePractical.class,
            mappedBy = "elective",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            optional = true)
    private ElectivePractical practical;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Student.class, 
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy = "electives")
    private Collection<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

ElectivePractical.java

```
public class ElectivePractical extends Practical {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne (targetEntity = Elective.class,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable (name = "ELECTIVE_PRACTICAL",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "ELEC_PRAC_ID",
            referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false), 
            inverseJoinColumns = 
            @JoinColumn (name = "ELEC_THEORY_ID",
            referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false))
    private Elective elective;
```

As you can see that `ElectivePractical` in `Elective.java` is set to `optional=true`

Yet when I try to `merge()` an Elective instance that has no practical I get the following error -:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.sts.entity.subjects.Elective.practical
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at com.sts.persistence.STSDao.addCourse(STSDao.java:250)
    at com.sts.validators.CourseValidator.commit(CourseValidator.java:558)
    at test.main.CourseTest.main(CourseTest.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.sts.entity.subjects.Elective.practical
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:839)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:821)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:826)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
    ... 3 more
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is this a bug in hibernate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `optional=true` element is only used for generation of the DDL, as well as validation of the schema. If you have created the database manually, the actual database column might well be `NOT NULL` even if your Hibernate-mapping says the opposite.

By the way, your mappings can be slimmed down, for instance I don't think you need `targetEntity` with newer versions of Hibernate.

Update:

I see you are using `mappedBy` on the same side as the `optional=true`-element. The `mappedBy`-element tells `Hibernate` that the other side of the relationship contains the actual mapping. It might be that this includes the `optional=true`-element, so that it is ignored. Try adding it to the other side of the relationship.

Comment: Schema Generation has been used here. Actually I think Hibernate is incorrectly assuming that the association between Elective and ElectivePractical is not null.

Comment: You should check your database schema at least, to determine whether the exception originates in the database. It might be an issue with the schema generation.